# Form validation with modals in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form inside a modal pop up. I am trying to run form validation on the inputs after the user attempts to submit the form. So far, I'm struggling to make things work.

In my view, I have the following (sorry if there are any syntax errors, I'm converting this from jade on the fly):

```
<script type="text/ng-template", id="modalVideoNew">
  <div class="ngdialog-message">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate name="newVideoForm">
   ...
      <div class="form-group">
      <label> Title </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="title", required='', ng-model="newVideoForm.title">
        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="validateInput('newVideoForm.title', 'required')"> This field is required</span>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</script>
```

And then in my controller, where I'm calling the ng-dialog pop up, I have this:

```
         $scope.newVideo = function() {
           ngDialog.openConfirm({
           template: 'modalVideoNew',
           className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
           scope: $scope
         }).then(function() {
           $scope.validateInput = function(name, type) {
             var input = $scope.newVideoForm[name];
           return (input.$dirty || $scope.submitted) && input.$error[type];
        };
          var newVideo = $scope.newVideoForm;
        ...
```

Right now, I am still able to submit the form, but once I open it back up I see the 'This field is required' error message. Also, the input is pre-filled with [object, Object] instead of an empty text input box.

Comment: can you please provide a plunker ?

Comment: Do you have a separate controller for your modal?

Answer (score 2):

A way of cleaning your model would work with using a model var that belongs to your parent controller and cleaning it in the callback. Check out how the template has attached your parent controller's var `FormData`.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j1re3dx4/) out

So about your validation, what I would recommend you is to have your own controller in it, no matter how much code it will have. It helps you keeping concepts of modularization and a better control over your scopes. This way will also facilitate a lot when validating.

Comment: This answer offers very sound advice, can cause all sorts of problems with cleaning up scope variables if you don't do this (I made this mistake). Much cleaner if you create a separate controller for the form +1